# When is it safe to rewrite git history when local branches are present?

Tags: git, url-rewriting, git-branch, rebase

I am learning git.

In this [book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Rebasing) I read that rebase is not safe when I pushed commits into public repository. It is clear. But what if I didn't pushed commit-X, but created local branches After commit-X are made and want to change this commit?

I tried to change name of the old commit in master branch using `git rebase -i HEAD~3` and see that hash has changed. Meanwhile in my work branch same commit didn't changе and have *different hash for this commit in master and work branch* now.

The created issue was fixed by simple `git rebase master`. But I wonder whether I was just lucky and can't I have a problem in such cases?

**What is the correct way to rewrite commit history if I have several branches, which depend on commits being rewritten?** Is rebasing always safe in such a cases? If not, then when exactly it is not safe? **What kind of changes I must avoid here to be safe?**

Comment: I think rebasing the work branches afterwards is all you can do.

Comment: Is rebasing always safe in such a cases? If not, then when exactly it is not safe? What kind of changes I must avoid here to be safe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you rewrite `commitX`, you go from:

```
              b--b (B1)
             /
x--x--X--y--z  (master)
          \
           b--b--b (B2)
```

To:

```
              b--b  (B1)
             /
x--x--X--y--z       
    \     \
     \     b--b--b  (B2)
      \
       x'--y'--z' (master)
```

Meaning your old branch is still there.

You can then **[`rebase --onto`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2369516/6309)**:

```
git checkout master
git rebase --onto z' z B1
git rebase --onto y' z B2
```

It is "safe", but can be a lot of work if you have many branches to rebase. In that last case, you can try automating those rebase, but it isn't always trivial: see for instance "[Git: How to rebase many branches (with the same base commit) at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/866218/6309)".

Comment: @klm123 "disappear", or rather be referenced only by your [local **reflog**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17859891/6309).

Comment: I mean physically, will git keep content of this oldMaster branch, or will it calculate it in case reflog is used?

Comment: @klm123 physically, the content is kept, in the reflog, for (by default) 90 days. It isn't calculated on demand. It is stored.

Comment: Thank you! Now it is much clear about safety during history rewriting.