# Why does git reflog show multiple batches of HEADs

Tags: git, git-reflog

I previously asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39708370/what-does-the-long-empty-space-in-git-reflog-signify-why-are-there-multiple-bat) but I closed it as it was a close duplicate of the same issue with `git log`. Now I have a similar question that why does git reflog show 'different lists of HEAD logs'?

If I use keyboard to go down I see from HEAD0 all the way to HEAD 247 which is where I `clone`d my repo. which sounds very logical and understandable YET I see another long list that is from HEAD 1 to HEAD 225 & then another that is from HEAD0 to HEAD 225 and then another that is from HEAD0 to HEAD 90. Why are there various versions of history? Or are they something else entirely?

**Bash Output sample**

```
7136d2c HEAD@{0}: checkout: moving from master to master
7136d2c HEAD@{1}: checkout: moving from xhh994 to master
7136d2c HEAD@{2}: merge master: Fast-forward
f50e2ef HEAD@{3}: checkout: moving from master to xhh994
// Lots of more lines
7136d2c HEAD@{90}: pull upstream master: Fast-forward
7136d2c HEAD@{0}: checkout: moving from master to master
7136d2c HEAD@{1}: checkout: moving from xhh994 to master
7136d2c HEAD@{2}: merge master: Fast-forward
f50e2ef HEAD@{3}: checkout: moving from master to xhh994
// Lots of more lines
7136d2c HEAD@{225}: pull upstream master: Fast-forward
7136d2c HEAD@{0}: checkout: moving from master to master
7136d2c HEAD@{1}: checkout: moving from xhh994 to master
7136d2c HEAD@{2}: merge master: Fast-forward
f50e2ef HEAD@{3}: checkout: moving from master to xhh994
// Lots of more lines
7136d2c HEAD@{225}: pull upstream master: Fast-forward
7136d2c HEAD@{0}: checkout: moving from master to master
7136d2c HEAD@{1}: checkout: moving from xhh994 to master
7136d2c HEAD@{2}: merge master: Fast-forward
f50e2ef HEAD@{3}: checkout: moving from master to xhh994
// Lots of more lines
7136d2c HEAD@{247}: clone from: github.mycompany.com/myproject
```

Why don't I only and only see:

```
7136d2c HEAD@{0}: checkout: moving from master to master
7136d2c HEAD@{1}: checkout: moving from xhh994 to master
7136d2c HEAD@{2}: merge master: Fast-forward
f50e2ef HEAD@{3}: checkout: moving from master to xhh994
// Lots of more lines
7136d2c HEAD@{247}: clone from: github.mycompany.com/myproject
```

Comment: Please add some example output to your question.

Comment: Your follow-up question, "what is a pager", is probably *much* more relevant here. I do not know whether you are using Windows, Linux, OS X, etc here; and whichever one you are using, it may also matter which terminal emulator you are using. In general, though, most terminal emulators give you a window with 24 or 50 or some other fixed number of lines of text. Programs must restrict their output to that many lines or fewer, or the earlier lines will scroll off the screen. A pager is designed to avoid the scrolling-off. If you're using your mouse to bring them back, you're fighting the pager.

Comment: @ScottWeldon I added output. This is what I see if I use keyboard to go down. Then if I scroll up using keyboard I get stuck at HEAD{0}. If I use mouse to scroll I see the HEAD{225} and all the rest...