# What is the 2nd column in the git reflog?

Tags: git, git-reflog

I just did a simple `git reflog` and this is the first few lines I got:

```
column1                 Column2                                Column3
2797a1d4 (HEAD -> master, upstream/master) HEAD@{0}: checkout: moving from master to master
2797a1d4 (HEAD -> master, upstream/master) HEAD@{1}: pull upstream master: Fast-forward
a461a29f HEAD@{2}: checkout: moving from master to master
a461a29f HEAD@{3}: reset: moving to HEAD
a461a29f HEAD@{4}: pull upstream master: Fast-forward
784f2cp3 (yy, alphabets, hotFix) HEAD@{5}: checkout: moving from yy to master
784f2cp3 (yy, alphabets, hotFix) HEAD@{6}: checkout: moving from master to yy
784f2cp3 (yy, alphabets, hotFix) HEAD@{7}: checkout: moving from alphabets to master
```

I'm trying to understand what each column represents. Reading from [this post](http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/02/09/reflog-your-safety-net.html) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17857723/whats-the-difference-between-git-reflog-and-log) I've already learned:

- Column1 is obviously the commit,
- Column2 is where I get confused. I understand the `HEAD@{0}` to `HEAD@{7}` concept. **Don't get the parts that are in the parenthesis!**. What does `(yy, alphabets, hotFix)` represent?
- Column3 is the action i.e. checkout/pull along with a message.

Additionally I'm uncertain as to why there is multiple lines of the same commit? Is it because different branches are all pointing to the same commit and there is no code changes between them?

Comment: I also read from [git-reflog's documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog), but from what I see it's either not mentioned or I'm not good with reading its manual. I just wish there was some documentation that would just tell you if you do this command, then these are the column labels. All I see in the help pages is each commands **options**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reflog tells you how `HEAD` has moved. There are more than three columns. The Git docs are obtuse about this. It turns out `git reflog` is just an alias for `git log` with some switches.

> `git reflog show` [the default] is an alias for `git log -g --abbrev-commit --pretty=oneline;`

```
784f2cp3 (yy, alphabets, hotFix) HEAD@{7}: checkout: moving from alphabets to master
```

1. `784f2cp3` The abbreviated commit.
2. `(yy, alphabets, hotFix)` The branch heads at this commit, just like `git log --decorate`.
3. `HEAD@{7}` The location of this commit relative to `HEAD`, added by `-g`.
4. `checkout` What command was run.
5. `moving from alphabets to master` A human readable description.

(4 and 5 are technically the same column.)

This says you were on branch `alphabets` and ran `git checkout master`.

> *Additionally I'm uncertain as to why there is multiple lines of the same commit? Is it because different branches are all pointing to the same commit and there is no code changes between them?*

Yes, exactly.

```
784f2cp3 (yy, alphabets, hotFix) HEAD@{5}: checkout: moving from yy to master
784f2cp3 (yy, alphabets, hotFix) HEAD@{6}: checkout: moving from master to yy
784f2cp3 (yy, alphabets, hotFix) HEAD@{7}: checkout: moving from alphabets to master
```

`yy`, `alphabets`, `hotFix`, and `master` were all on the same commit. Checking out between them simply changes which branch head will be moved the next commit.

The others might be internal `HEAD` movements which happen when you run `git pull`. `git pull` is a combination of `git fetch` and `git merge`.

Comment: Thanks. What does `HEAD -> master` mean here?

Comment: @Honey It means `master` is currently checked out, `HEAD` points at `master`.

Comment: I just did another `git reflog` and got : `(HEAD -> develop, origin/develop, origin/HEAD)`. What does `origin/HEAD` mean here? I understand the other two...

Comment: @Honey It's the position of `HEAD` on the remote repository called `origin`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354312/why-is-origin-head-shown-when-running-git-branch-r) for more.