# git checkout removes git log history

Tags: git

Ive got two commits in my `git log`

```
commit a38056f9da4dcf48c188e79fe632b3624e6ffef4 (HEAD, main)
Author: user
    commit 2

commit 801608941f024901799208e328bb0d3908c2ba7a
Author: user

    commit 1
```

, I wanna go back to commit 1, which I can do with `git checkout 801608941f024901799208e328bb0d3908c2ba7a`.
Problem is, when I do this, my `git log` turns to

```
commit 801608941f024901799208e328bb0d3908c2ba7a
Author: user

    commit 1
```

And I can't find the SHA for commit 2 anymore. If I find commit 2's SHA by scrolling up to my first `git log` then `git checkout` commit 2's SHA, I go back to commit 2's snapshot as expected, but it's annoying that the `git log` doesn't show commit 2's SHA  Is this normal? If so, how am I supposed to find the commit history for `commit 2` now?

Comment: If you only run `git log`, it will show you the history up to the commit where you are on at the moment... so, you go back to the first commit of the history, git log will only show you that commit... you can always ask for logging something else like `git log main` or `git log -a` (to show you all branches/tags). You could also go back to main and then log there. `git checkout main; git log`

Comment: or you can use `git reflog` to check. This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17857723/whats-the-difference-between-git-reflog-and-log) contains discussion on differences between `git log` and `git reflog`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Summary

Run:

```
git switch main
```

or:

```
git checkout main
```

## Detail

Git hasn't *removed* anything.  You just can't *see* it.  Here's why:  The `git log` command works by *going backwards*.

History, in a Git repository, is nothing more or less than the commits that are in that repository.  Git *finds* commits by their big ugly hash IDs:

- `a38056f9da4dcf48c188e79fe632b3624e6ffef4`
- `801608941f024901799208e328bb0d3908c2ba7a`

Git *desperately needs* these hash IDs in order to find the commits.  But these hash IDs are very bad for humans (quick, is `801608941f024901799208e328bb0d3908c2ba7a` the same as `801608941f024901797208e328bb0d3908c2ba7a`?).  So we don't normally use the hash IDs.  Git *does* use the hash IDs, but Git provides us *branch names* and *tag names* and many other kinds of names.  Those are what we normally use.

Each commit stores two things:

- Directly, each commit stores some *metadata*, giving information such as the name and email address of the person who made the commit.
- Indirectly, each commit stores a *full snapshot of every file*.

All of this stuff, once inside a commit, is completely read-only: it can never be changed, not even by Git itself, as long as you *retrieve* that commit by its big ugly hash ID.  That hash ID is the "true name" of that commit.

Inside each commit's metadata, Git stores a list of *previous* commits, and this is how `git log` actually works: it starts at some particular commit, which has some particular big ugly hash ID, and `git log` shows you that commit.  Then `git log` uses that commit's *metadata* to find the *previous* commit.  The `git log` command now shows *that* commit, and then uses its metadata to step backwards once again.

The end result of this is that you see all the commits, one at a time, *backwards*, from wherever you start (or is it "end"?), following the internal chains that Git forges as you work:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

Here the uppercase letters stand in for those big ugly hash IDs, so `H` is short for some Hash.  If you give Git the hash ID of `H`, it shows you `H`, then it uses `H` to find the hash ID for `G`.  We say that commit `H` *points to* earlier commit `G`.  Git then shows `G`, and then uses `G`'s metadata to find the hash ID for `F`, and so on.

But: if you run `git log` *without* giving it a hash ID, how does it know where to start?  The answer is that Git has the notion of a *current commit*, which Git finds using the special, magic name `HEAD`.

#### HEAD usually contains a *branch name*

Because hash IDs are bad for humans, we tend not to use them.  Git offers us the option of creating any number of *branch names*.  Each branch name stores exactly one hash ID, and whatever hash ID is "inside" the branch name, that's the *last* commit that's "on" that branch:

```
... <-F <-G <-H   <--main
```

Here the name `main` *points to* `H`, just as `H` points to `G` and `G` points to `F` and so on.  So `git log main` will start at `H` and work backwards.

We can have as many branch names as we like, all pointing directly to commit `H`:

```
...--G--H   <-- main, develop, feature1, feature2
```

To remember *which name* is the *current name*, Git will attach the special name `HEAD` to exactly one of these branch names:

```
...--G--H   <-- main, develop, feature1 (HEAD), feature2
```

Here we are "on" branch `feature1`—running `git status` will say `on branch feature1`—and `git log`, without any starting point, will use the name `feature1` to find commit `H`, and show that commit, then `G` and `F` and whatever.

#### Detached HEAD mode

If, however, we run:

```
git checkout <hash-id>
```

for some big ugly hash ID, Git stores that hash ID *directly* in the special name `HEAD`, and now we have:

```
...--F   <-- HEAD
      \
       G--H   <-- main, develop, ...
```

Running `git log` now starts at commit `F` and works backwards.  What happened to commits `G` and `H`?  Nothing at all: they're still in there.  You just need to start `git log` *at* commit `H`, to see them.  To do that, you can run:

```
git log main
```

since `main` points to `H`; or you can `git switch main` or `git checkout main` to *re-attach* `HEAD` to the branch name, so that `git log` starts there.

#### Note that commits are often on many branches

Given:

```
...--G--H   <-- main, develop, feature1 (HEAD), feature2
```

which branch(es) are the commits on?

The answer is: *all of them!*

If we make a *new* commit now, though, here's what happens:

```
...--G--H   <-- main, develop, feature2
         \
          I   <-- feature1 (HEAD)
```

Git will not only write out the new commit, giving it a new unique hash ID (the big ugly hash IDs are unique), it will set up the new commit so that it points back to commit `H`—the commit we *were* using as the current commit just a moment ago—and then write the *new* commit's hash ID into the current *branch name*.

This is how branches normally grow, one commit at a time.

There is a whole lot more, but these are essential things to know, to use Git.